# Getting a value of td of a selected tr in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Below is my table

```
<table>
    <tr class=chargeTR>
        <td id=chargeTD>
            charge1
        </td>
    </tr class=chargeTR>
        <td id=chargeTD>
            charge2
        </td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

Below is my jQuery call

```
$(".chargeTR").each(function() { // this line works fine
        $.get("process.php", {
            value: $(this).find("#chargeTD").val(), // I must be doing something wrong here...
        }, function(theXML){
            alert(theXML);
        });
});
```

I cannot get the value "charge1" and "charge2".

Can somebody please correct me in this?

Comment: multiple IDs of the same name is bad practice. IDs are intended to be used once in the page. Use class names in cases of repeating elements with a parent ID. In your case, assign the ID to the table and your call would start with $("#idOfTable tr).each(function() {

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `.text()` or `.html()` instead of `.val()`, since `.val` is intended to get `value=""` attributes from forms.

Answer (score 1):

You may also need to use $.trim() to get exact text without whitespace.

```
$.trim($(this).find("#chargeTD").text())
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked form me:

HTML:

```
<tr class="" id="tr_id" >
    <td class="l_id">7283630222</td>
</tr>
<tr class="" id="tr_id" >
    <td class="l_id">7276684022</td>
</tr>
<p id="leadID">-lead id here-</p>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr#tr_id").click(function() {
        $("#leadID").text($(this).find("td.l_id").text());
    }); 
});
```