# .val on a specific child not returning any value [JQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm inside of a .each loop trying to access a specific table cell (td) in a set of rows. Each row has three cells with the classes of Id, Name, and Practice.

Code:

```
@foreach (var client in ViewBag.ClientList.getDatabase())
    {
        <tr class="ClientRow">
            <td class="Id">@client.Id</td>
            <td class="Name">@client.getClientName</td>
            <td class="Practice">@client.getPracticeID</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

//Some time later when trying to access from the foreach

```
$(".ClientRow").each(function (index) {
var Name = $(this).children(".Name").val();
var ID = $(this).children(".Practice").val();
```

The Name and ID vars always seem to return empty strings.

Comment: Use `.text` or `.html` instead of `.val`.

Comment: You need to review the Jquery api doc. It clearly states "The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea. " http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a value of td of a selected tr in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894604/getting-a-value-of-td-of-a-selected-tr-in-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.val()` is used to retrieve the `value` attribute (it's a shortcut for `.attr('value')`), and this can only be used on elements that support such a thing (for example `<input />`, `<select>` or `<textarea>`.

Here's what the [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/) say about the `val()` function:

> The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form
>   elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`. In the case of
>   `select` elements, it returns `null` when no option is selected and an
>   array containing the value of each selected option when there is at
>   least one and it is possible to select more because the `multiple`
>   attribute is present.

To get the `innerHTML` or the text content of an element, you should use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

For example:

```
$(".ClientRow").each(function (index) {
var Name = $(this).children(".Name").text();
var ID = $(this).children(".Practice").text();
```

`.text()` returns the actual text of the element (without any HTML).
`.html()` will return the `innerHTML` of the element.

Comment: aaahhhh. That wasn't clear in the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Reading a little further into the docs should help clarify any confusion (but I've added the relevant excerpt to the answer for completeness anyway).

Answer (score 0):

val() is used for inputs, in your case you have to use:

```
$(".ClientRow").each(function (index) {
var Name = $(this).children(".Name").text();
var ID = $(this).children(".Practice").text();
```